# Parallel sieve of eratosthenes produces wrong output based on number of threads

Tags: c++, openmp, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is the approach I'm using for parallelization:

1. p = Process ID, N = total number of processes, n = input size
2. Each process is assigned `n/N` numbers, ranging from index `p*n/N` to `(p+1)*n/N-1`.
3. When process 0 finds a prime number, all its multiples are marked in parallel.
4. Finally, each process counts the number of primes in its assigned range and adds it to the global count.

Using C++/OpenMP for parallelization. Before calling the function, I set the maximum number of threads with `omp_set_num_threads()`.

```
// p is thread ID, N is total number of threads, n is the array size
#define LOWER_BOUND(p, N, n) p == 0 ? 2 : (p * n / N)
#define UPPER_BOUND(p, N, n) p == (N - 1) ? (n - 1) : (p + 1) * (n / N) - 1

size_t parallel_soe(std::vector<std::atomic<bool>>& A) {
    size_t n = A.size();
    size_t sqrt_n = sqrt(n);
    for (size_t i = 2; i <= sqrt_n; i++) {
        if (A[i] == true) continue;
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            uint16_t p = omp_get_thread_num();
            uint16_t N = omp_get_num_threads();
            size_t lower_bound = LOWER_BOUND(p, N, n);
            size_t upper_bound = UPPER_BOUND(p, N, n);
            size_t smallest_multiple = std::max(i * i, lower_bound);
            size_t remainder = smallest_multiple % i;
            if (remainder) smallest_multiple += i - remainder;
            for (size_t j = smallest_multiple; j <= upper_bound; j += i)
                A[j] = true;
        }
    }
    // Count number of primes
    size_t prime_count = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        uint16_t p = omp_get_thread_num();
        uint16_t N = omp_get_num_threads();
        size_t lower_bound = LOWER_BOUND(p, N, n);
        size_t upper_bound = UPPER_BOUND(p, N, n);
        size_t count = 0;
        for (size_t i = lower_bound; i <= upper_bound; i++)
            if (A[i] == false)
                count++;
        #pragma omp atomic
        prime_count += count;
    }
    return prime_count;
}
```

The value returned by the function is correct when maximum threads are set to 2, 4, 8, 10, and 16, but not for 6, 12, and 14. I'm running it on a 4 core Intel i5.

This is my output log:

```
Finding primes under: 10000
================================
[2-parallel]  Found 1229 primes in 542 microseconds
[4-parallel]  Found 1229 primes in 3173 microseconds
[6-parallel]  Found 1228 primes in 2353 microseconds
[8-parallel]  Found 1229 primes in 3600 microseconds
[10-parallel] Found 1229 primes in 3227 microseconds
[12-parallel] Found 1227 primes in 2778 microseconds
[14-parallel] Found 1226 primes in 2248 microseconds
[16-parallel] Found 1229 primes in 2320 microseconds

Finding primes under: 100000
================================
[2-parallel]  Found 9592 primes in 5186 microseconds
[4-parallel]  Found 9592 primes in 10351 microseconds
[6-parallel]  Found 9591 primes in 9859 microseconds
[8-parallel]  Found 9592 primes in 8500 microseconds
[10-parallel] Found 9592 primes in 12294 microseconds
[12-parallel] Found 9591 primes in 8300 microseconds
[14-parallel] Found 9582 primes in 9252 microseconds
[16-parallel] Found 9592 primes in 8557 microseconds

Finding primes under: 1000000
================================
[2-parallel]  Found 78498 primes in 36091 microseconds
[4-parallel]  Found 78498 primes in 43570 microseconds
[6-parallel]  Found 78498 primes in 48176 microseconds
[8-parallel]  Found 78498 primes in 44201 microseconds
[10-parallel] Found 78498 primes in 43645 microseconds
[12-parallel] Found 78498 primes in 49175 microseconds
[14-parallel] Found 78494 primes in 47411 microseconds
[16-parallel] Found 78498 primes in 53602 microseconds
```

Comment: You have 2 separated `#pragma omp parallel`. you can test which one is the problematic one.

Comment: The sieve does not lend itself to being very easily parallel.  Your code here is complex, obviously error-prone, difficult to maintain, and performs worse the more threads you throw at it.  To top this off, even your best performance seems to be about 10 times slower than a [naive single-threaded implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/EYW9ez7jW).  There's too little work involved in marking non-primes to justify the overhead of all the thread synchronization.

Comment: you need a prime number of threads

Comment: @paddy I only showed the output for smaller numbers (under 10^6), so of course the overhead is unjustified. What optimizations would you recommend?

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem with the code but putting function-like behaviour in a macro is discouraged in various coding standards (see the references section in [this](https://rules.sonarsource.com/c/RSPEC-960) SonarSource rule). The compiler will probably inline both `LOWER_BOUND` and `UPPER_BOUND` since they can be implemented as single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It had nothing to do with parallel execution, I just had a calculation error when computing the bounds.

This is the correct formula for computing lower bound:

```
#define LOWER_BOUND(p, N, n) p == 0 ? 2 : p * (n / N)
```

Notice the paranthesis around `n/n`.